# merge with condition on two dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

similar to the unanswered question here: [Merge two dataframes with condition on timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40324606/merge-two-dataframes-with-condition-on-timestamp)
but my question is more general and not time-series specific

I have two dataframes I want to merge with a proximity condition on two columns from both dataframes. in SQL I would have done something like

`select * from 
   (select * from A) T1
   inner join
   (select * from B) T2
  on T1.user = T2.user 
  and T1.label - T2.label < 2`

what I'm looking for is a canincal way to do the above in R, something like-

```
merge(x,y,by='user', condition = x$label - y$label <=2 )
```

so the following should be without rows 3,7,11,12,13,15 etc....

```
set.seed(1212)
a <- data.frame(user=rep(paste("u",1:3,sep=''),4),label=sample.int(10,12,T))
b <- data.frame(user=rep(paste("u",1:3,sep=''),4),label=sample.int(10,12,T))

merge(a,b,by='user')

   user label.x label.y
1    u1       3       1
2    u1       3       3
3    u1       3      10
4    u1       3       5
5    u1       3       1
6    u1       3       3
7    u1       3      10
8    u1       3       5
9    u1       1       1
10   u1       1       3
11   u1       1      10
12   u1       1       5
13   u1       4       1
14   u1       4       3
15   u1       4      10
16   u1       4       5
17   u2       7       1
18   u2       7       7
19   u2       7       4
20   u2       7       2
21   u2       2       1
22   u2       2       7
23   u2       2       4
24   u2       2       2
25   u2       6       1
26   u2       6       7
27   u2       6       4
28   u2       6       2
29   u2       1       1
30   u2       1       7
31   u2       1       4
32   u2       1       2
33   u3       8       7
34   u3       8       1
35   u3       8       7
36   u3       8       4
37   u3       1       7
38   u3       1       1
39   u3       1       7
40   u3       1       4
41   u3      10       7
42   u3      10       1
43   u3      10       7
44   u3      10       4
45   u3       9       7
46   u3       9       1
47   u3       9       7
48   u3       9       4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With base R, I will try:

```
subset(merge(a, b, by = 'user'), label.x - label.y <= 2)
```

If the data is huge, we can try non-equi join from `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(a)
setDT(b)

a[, label.a := label - 2]
b[, label.b := label]
y <- a[b, on = .(user, label.a <= label.b), allow.cartesian=TRUE][, label.a := NULL]
```

> ```
> > head(y)
>    user label i.label
> 1:   u1     1       1
> 2:   u1     3       1
> 3:   u1     3       1
> 4:   u2     1       7
> 5:   u2     2       7
> 6:   u2     6       7
> ```

Here, `label` in `y` is the `label` from `a`, and `label.i` is the `label` from `b`.

Or more explictly, use `J` expression:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(a)
setDT(b)

a[, label2 := label - 2]
y <- a[
    b,
    .(user, label.a = label, label.b = i.label),
    on = .(user, label2 <= label),
    allow.cartesian=TRUE]
```

Comment: This will work of course but I'm looking for a way to condition the merge itself since.actual data is huge and subletting after the join is too expensive....

Comment: @ZahiroMor, try `data.table` (see my edited answer.)